# How to Clone a entire TagGroup from a image to another image?

Tags: image, tags, dm-script

I have an image with TagGroup (many individual tags). And I would like to crop the image but still keep the same TagGroup. It seems that I have to create a new image and clone the original taggroup to this new image.

I do not want to manipulate the Tags individually because they are way too much and too slow. I saw there are commands to operate them as a whole (like TagGroupCopyTag(); TagGroupCopyTagsFrom(); TagGroupClone()); But I didn't find any command to attach that entire TagGroup as a whole to a image. This may be a silly question but could anyone tell me that?

Thanks

Comment: Not a silly question at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it step by step, then you need to get the images, then the taggroups of the images and then use the command to copy and clone. (note that you want to clone or you will get the *identical* taggroup, i.e. shared memory as long as the images are open in DM.)

```
image srcImg := A
image dstImg := B
taggroup srcTg = ImageGetTagGroup( srcImg )
taggroup dstTg = ImageGetTagGroup( dstImg )
taggroup srcTgCopy = TagGroupClone( srcTg )
TagGroupCopyTagsFrom( dstTg, srcTg )
```

But you can easily "combine" that all into a single line as well:

```
B.ImageGetTagGroup().TagGroupCopyTagsFrom( A.ImageGetTagGroup().TagGroupClone() )
```

Finally, if you goal is to create a "copy" of a subsection of an image (including tags and calibration) I would recommend something like this:

```
image srcImg := A
image cropped := ImageClone( srcImg[0,0,10,10] )
ShowImage( cropped )
```

Comment: Oh. that is a surprise that ImageClone() from subarea actually keeps the tags and calibration. I tested it before posting this question and it gave me different result. Probably i was missing the important colon by mistake.

Comment: I am rotating a image and crop a subarea out. Seems that the rotated image (new:=Rotate(img, angle)) doesn't keep tags and calibration already. Then I have to use the the TagGroupClone().

Comment: From your example, It seems that the defined tags actually is always linked to the image. Any changes to the tags will be effect on the image immediately. So instead of adding a tag to an image (that is what to do individually), we could grab the original tag from a image and modify it. That is a surprise for me.

Comment: "TagGroups" are objects. Each image has a "root" taggroup you can get access to, which you then can modify (f.e. adding to it). But you can also create new "loose" tagGroup objects and modify them if you just need some sort of "structured" data container. (You can also save/load them.) The "preferences" of DM are another "root" taggroup. You get it by "GetPerstistentTagGroup()". The commands "SetNumberNote() SetPersistentNumberNote() etc. are just convenience wrapper-shortcuts to this. TagGroups are very versatile and its useful to know them well in scripting!

Comment: Yes, the command Rotate() creates a *new* image (just data). A "trick" can be to pre-create a "cloned" image (of appropriate size) and then use "=" not ":=" to copy the data only. But it's possibly "cleaner" to copy tags (and and calibrations) instead.